# Number of representations of an irrational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I thought about this question. I do not know if this is on-topic, but i like it..
How many representations are possible of an irrational number?
I know that the famous $\pi$ has two representations - $\frac{22}{7} , \frac{333}{106}$. Of course these are not perfect, just good approximations. Can there be any more such good representations? What also about $e?$ . It is represented by an infinite series.. Also, can numerous representations exist, and is there any explicit formula?(is it impossible, and can this be proved)?

Comment: What do you mean by "good"? $15$ is a representation of $\pi$. Of course, it is not perfect, just a bad approximation. What makes $\frac{22}7$ "good"?

Comment: I mean error is very less like some $+/- .9$

Comment: You surely know what i try to mean.. i am just too amateur to explain

Comment: I can tell more or less what you are trying to do, but in order to get an actual, sensible, specific answer, you have to be a bit clearer about the _details_ of what you want. Of course, there are general answers like the one below.

Answer (score 1):

$22\over7$ and $333\over106$ happen to be rational numbers that are close to $\pi$. There are many others, such as $355\over113$, and for any irrational number, there are rational numbers that are (arbitrarily) close. There are also all kinds of infinite series for any irrational number; one of those is the infinite series that comes from the irrational number’s decimal expansion. Depending on what direction interests you, there is a lot to be explored. One of many possibilities is to look into the subject of [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), which can be used as a tool to find particularly “good” rational approximations of irrational numbers.

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to find infinite solutions or if thee are finite, then any algorithm for it

Comment: It depends on your definition of “solution,” but there are definitely infinitely many different fractions that approximate $\pi$ or any irrational (or even rational) number as well as you want. The sequence of numerators for one such list is here http://oeis.org/A002485 and the denominators are here http://oeis.org/A002486. So for example, if you take the 7th number in each list, you see that $103993\over33102$ is one of the fractions. Another list is ${31\over10},{314\over100},{3141\over1000},{31415\over10000},{314159\over100000}...$.